# Can't start service as a specific user?

Tags: linux, sudo

Been fighting with Linux for the past few days. For whatever reason I can't start my service as a specific user. If I try to start my service as a specific user it will not work:

```
sudo -u logAdmin /sbin/service logService start
```

However; if I run the service as the root user it will start.

```
sudo /sbin/service logService start
```

I am not really sure how fix this. The user definitely exists. When I check for the user using:

```
grep "^logAdmin" /etc/passwd
```

I get back:

```
logAdmin:x:600:600:logAdmin Application Account:/app:/bin/bash
```

I also made to give appropriate permissions to the script

/etc/init.d and sh files with:

```
chown logAdmin:logAdmin /app/logService
```

And I registered the service:

```
/sbin/chkconfig logService on
```

I also checked the permission of my user on the init script and got back:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 logAdmin logAdmin 1228 May 11 17:39 /etc/init.d/logService
```

I have tried everything to get this working! Why is it running the sudo root user but won't run when I try to start it as another user??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`service` **must** be run as root. The initscript is responsible for starting the application as a different user.